# Where does "they can't lay us off if they can't find us" come from?

Tags: phrases

In some film, I saw a man wearing a T-shirt written "they can't lay us off if they can't find us" with some picture on the middle of it.

I also found a mug with that same sentence and picture carved and it is on sale.
What is this? Do you have any idea? At least, I can guess it is really popular thing.

Well, Something like a quotation of someone?
Please tell me about all of this. Of course I searched internet on it myself.
But I failed to search it in detail.

Answer (score 2):

This is a joke.  To "lay someone off" is to dismiss him from his job because he is no longer needed.  The joke is in the idea that in a large company "we" could find ways to "hide in plain sight" so to speak, so that Human Resources wouldn't know where we were.  In such a case, they would be unable to take their intended action of dismissing us from our jobs.

Comment: As for where it came from, I don't know a precise source, but I would wager that it originated during a down time in the economy when layoffs were relatively rampant.